# Issues creating has_many through relation (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, web

This may be a beginner question but it really has had me stumped tonight. I have 3 models: Play, User, and Works_on

app/models/play.rb

```
class Play < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :works_on
  has_many :users, through: :works_on, :foreign_key => 'user_id'
end
```

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :works_on
  has_many :plays, through: :works_on, :foreign_key => 'play_id'
end
```

app/model/works_on.rb

```
class WorksOn < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :play
end
```

When I try to run

```
<%= @play.users.each{|user| user.first_name }  %>
```

in app/views/plays/show.html.erb, I get the error

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: works_ons.play_id: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "works_ons" ON "users"."id" = "works_ons"."user_id" WHERE "works_ons"."play_id" = ?
```

I have tried creating a migration to manually add foreign keys to the models but have not been able to get it to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why you explicitly mention foreign key, even if you done it with `RoR` conventions? Why you don't prefer `has_and_belongs_to_many` association if you don't want to explicitly create WorksOn class objects?

Comment: I would like to add an attribute (role/responsibility) to the work_on relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to add the foreign keys to the migration. Not sure why this wasn't working for me initially, but it ends up working. Thanks everyone!

```
class CreateWorksOns < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :works_ons do |t|
      t.integer :play_id, null:false
      t.integer :user_id, null:false

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way how to treat with what abhinavmsra pointed is that in ActiveRecord replationships you can specify the class, which the model is related to through the `class_name` option. So you add the `class_name` option to the `User` and `Play` models.

```
has_many :works_on, :class_name => 'WorksOn'
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not working for me. It's giving the same error, no column work_ons.play_id

Answer (score 1):

For has_many association, association names should be plural.
 Try replacing

```
:works_on
```

with

```
:works_ons
```